# Nvidia drivers crashing on boot

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

Recently I reinstalled Windows 7 and installed the newest Nvidia drivers. When I restarted computer, it'd restart itself again during Windows' boot sequence (Windows logo flying in) with no error message. After couple of tries, it boots up properly. It's always random. Sometimes I boot up on first try, sometimes it takes me 45mins of restarting to get it working. So I tried different drivers. 295 BETA and 285 WHQL kept doing this. 280 WHQL seems to be more stable for now, but I can't imagine myself being stuck on old drivers forever. I haven't found anyone else with such issues. Could it be hardware problem with my GFX? Or perhaps conflicts with some other hardware (which seems to be unlikely as this happened on clean Windows install)?

I have [Nvidia GTX460](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-460-us.html) and Windows 7 64-bit. Not sure what else is relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping out your PSU for one you know works, and check your motherboard for [defective capacitors.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague)

Comment: It was old PSU, +12V line supplied only 18A, but I needed 24 for GFX. No idea why it sometimes booted normally though.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating BIOS and check if all expansion boards are seated properly.

Comment: Everything is seated properly and I got the latest non-beta BIOS.

Comment: Motherboard model...
RAM type used (and result of memtest86)